# Prevent blinking screen when using interceptor in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, interceptor, angular-ui-router

I use interceptor in order to catch 401 responses from server. When I got 401 response I broadcast a message: `$rootScope.$broadcast('auth:loginRequired');`

In the `.run()` method of my module I listen to this event:

```
$rootScope.$on('auth:loginRequired', function() {
    $state.go('login');
});
```

(Here I use ui-router library, not a default routing system)
So, when I visit some page where a request to server is being send and I get 401 response I get redirected to login page. But until I don't get response I see the page and only after response I get redirected to login, so the screen blinks.

How to prevent that?